# jQuery UI CSS Framework Information

Tags: jquery-ui

Does anyone know of any good tutorials, blogs etc on usage of the jQuery UI CSS Framework. I have read everything on the Jquery website but the documentation is quite poor. Via google I have been unable to find any additional information other then what is on the JQuery website. I know some good material must exist, but does anyone know where it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found these links that might be interesting for you:

[The jQuery UI CSS Framework – Part 1: Intro and How To Style a Button](http://www.fbloggs.com/2010/01/20/the-jquery-ui-css-framework-part-1-intro-and-how-to-style-a-button/)
[The jQuery UI CSS Framework – Part 2: How To Create Widget-style Boxes](http://www.fbloggs.com/2010/02/03/the-jquery-ui-css-framework-part-2-how-to-create-widget-style-boxes/)
[TOC Tutorial JQuery User Interface](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/TOC-Tutorial-JQuery-User-Interface-P1030.html)
[How to jQuery - Theming jQuery UI](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/68404841/How-to-jQuery---Theming-jQuery-UI)

The site seems unreachable but it normally is, i guess it's just temporary:
[Styling Buttons and Toolbars with the jQuery UI CSS Framework](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/styling_buttons_and_toolbars_with_the_jquery_ui_css_framework/)
[Develop Your Own jQuery “ThemeRoller-Ready” Components](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/developer_your_own_jquery_themeroller_ready_components/)